# Save list output after filtering onto text file

Tags: python, list, file, text

I want to save list below output onto a text file

```
with open("selectedProd.txt", 'w') as f:
   for x in myprod["prod"]:
      if x["type"]=="discount" or x["type"]=="normal" or x["type"]=="members" :
         f.write(x["name"],x["id"], x["price"])
```

I'm getting error

```
f.write(x["name"],x["id"], x["price"])
TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

Expected text file output as below

```
item1 111 2.00
item2 222 5.00
item3 444 1.00
item4 666 5.00
item5 212 7.00
```

Please advise further. Thanks

**Both solution below works one for python2.7 and python3.6 above**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error says, `f.write()` only takes one argument but you are giving it three. Instead of that you can do:

```
f.write("{} {} {}".format(x["name"],x["id"],x["price"]))
```

Answer (score 1):

`wirte` function only take one argument, So you have to convert your arguments into one single string and pass it one at a time,

```
with open("selectedProd.txt", 'w') as f:
   for x in myprod["prod"]:
      if x["type"]=="discount" or x["type"]=="normal" or x["type"]=="members" :
         # for string convertion I used f-strings
         context = '{} {} {}'.format(x["name"], x["id"], x["price"])
         f.write(context)
```

Comment: thanks for your input and advise... but i got syntax error when run over python 2.7...does it compatible to run with 2.7?

Comment: Sorry didn't know you were using 2.7, F-string introduce in python 3.6 and work with same version and above, in your case format should be the case so I updated the answer.

Comment: Your solution is taken shall run v3.6 and above as it use f-string. Thanks for sharing and appreciate your support. This answer is useful. Thanks